# cmake tries to link resource file

Tags: macos, linker, resources, cmake, bundle

### How can I prevent cmake from linking MACOSX bundle resource files ?

When I add a resource file to a MACOSX application bundle, it is taken by the linker due to its `.obj` postfix. The linker tries to link it without success. He writes a warning:

```
Linking CXX executable mwe.app/Contents/MacOS/mwe
ld: warning: ignoring file ../star.obj, file was built for unsupported file format
( 0x23 0x20 0x42 0x6C 0x65 0x6E 0x64 0x65 0x72 0x20 0x76 0x32 0x2E 0x37 0x30 0x20 ) 
which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../star.obj
```

Of course he cannot link it because `star.obj` is a 3D model text file in the [obj format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file):

```
# Blender v2.70 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'star.blend'
o Plane
v 0.510396 -0.000389 0.998397
v -0.926169 -0.000017 -0.001603
v 0.510396 0.000355 -1.001603
[..and many more vertices]
```

The resulting problem is; the file is not put into the MACOSX bundle folder because the linker ignored it.

```
VisorZ@Mac ~/MWE> ll build/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 Stephan  staff    62B  6 Aug 22:36 star.off
```

(See, `star.obj` is missing here) ------------------------------------^

#### I would like to exclude that obj file from the link file lists via cmake.

But neither the source file properties

- MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION,
- EXTERNAL_OBJECT FALSE,
- LANGUAGE "myMODEL"

nor the target property

- RESOURCE

can do that. Here is a minimum working example CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Minimum Working Example to create mwe.app on MACOSX with linker
# trying to process *.obj files which are marked as resource files

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(mwe)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( 
    star.obj        # 3D model as OBJ txt file
    star.off        # 3D model as OFF txt file
    PROPERTIES 
    MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources 
    ) 

ADD_EXECUTABLE( 
    ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    MACOSX_BUNDLE   # needs to be second argument, enables bundling
    helloworld.cpp  # will be compiled
    star.obj        # will not be bundled because it will be taken by linker 
    star.off        # will be bundled 
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HEADER_FILE_ONLY` and try not to think too much about the name of it.

```
set_source_files_properties( 
    star.obj        # 3D model as OBJ txt file
    star.off        # 3D model as OFF txt file
    PROPERTIES 
    HEADER_FILE_ONLY ON 
)
```

Comment: I tested it; it works fine. The files are bundled if my properties and your property are combined. Please do not forget to add the line `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources` at the end of the properties. Otherwise bundling will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the linker from trying to link the files you can add them to a custom target as such:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (testTarget SOURCES myFile.obj myFile.off)
```

This is especially handy for having files show up in your project tree but not having them compiled/linked.

Comment: I tested that and it did not change the error behavior of the linker.